# Problem installing Anaconda (GUI) on Ventura 13.2.1

Tags: install, ventura

When trying to install Anaconda on Intel MacBook Pro running Ventura 13.2.1, the GUI fails (the terminal way seems to work ok).

Here is the log:

```bash
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: @(#)PROGRAM:Install  PROJECT:Install-1000
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: @(#)PROGRAM:Installer  PROJECT:Installer-1131
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Hardware: MacBookPro14,1 @ 2.30 GHz (x 4), 8192 MB RAM
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Running OS Build: macOS 13.2.1 (22D68)
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Env: USER=ME
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Env: COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Env: __CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.installer
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Env: LOGNAME=ME
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Env: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.1Fm3z4nL7H/Listeners
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Env: HOME=/Users/ME
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Env: SHELL=/bin/bash
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Env: TMPDIR=/var/folders/dy/5_msn8t97r1g80_q0_nzgfg00000gn/T/
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Env: __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Env: XPC_SERVICE_NAME=application.com.apple.installer.1152921500312079933.1152921500312079938
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Env: XPC_FLAGS=0x0
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Anaconda3 2023.09-0  Installation Log
2023-10-09 19:55:14+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Opened from: /Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg
2023-10-09 19:55:15+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Product archive /Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg trustLevel=350
2023-10-09 19:55:15+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: External component packages (4) trustLevel=350
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: ================================================================================
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: User picked Standard Install
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Choices selected for installation:
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]:     Install: ""
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]:     Install: "Install Anaconda3"
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]:         Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#prepare_installation.pkg : io.continuum.pkg.prepare_installation : 2023.09-0
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]:         Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#run_installation.pkg : io.continuum.pkg.run_installation : 0
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]:     Install: "Run the post-install script"
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]:         Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#user_post_install.pkg : io.continuum.pkg.user_post_install : 0
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]:     Install: "Add conda initialization to the shell"
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]:         Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#pathupdate.pkg : io.continuum.pkg.pathupdate : 0
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: ================================================================================
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: It took 0.00 seconds to summarize the package selections.
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: location = file://localhost
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: file://localhost/Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#prepare_installation.pkg
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: file://localhost/Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#run_installation.pkg
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: file://localhost/Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#user_post_install.pkg
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: file://localhost/Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#pathupdate.pkg
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Set authorization level to none for session
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Packages have been authorized for installation.
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Will use PK session
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Using authorization level of none for IFPKInstallElement
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: PackageKit: Bypassing the enforcement checker since the destination is read/write
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Starting installation:
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Configuring volume "Untitled"
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Preparing disk for local booted install.
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Free space on "Untitled": 96.53 GB (96525078528 bytes).
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Create temporary directory "/var/folders/dy/5_msn8t97r1g80_q0_nzgfg00000gn/T//Install.1961559O3RE"
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: IFPKInstallElement (4 packages)
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Current Path: /System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP installd[67063]: PackageKit: Adding client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=19615, uid=501 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer)
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: PackageKit: Enqueuing install with framework-specified quality of service (utility)
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP installd[67063]: PackageKit: Set reponsibility for install to 19615
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP installd[67063]: PackageKit: Hosted team responsibility for install set to team:(Z5788K4JT7)
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP installd[67063]: PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP installd[67063]: PackageKit: request=PKInstallRequest <4 packages, destination=/Users/ME>
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP installd[67063]: PackageKit: packages=(
        "PKLeopardPackage <id=io.continuum.pkg.prepare_installation, version=2023.09-0, url=file:///Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#prepare_installation.pkg>",
        "PKLeopardPackage <id=io.continuum.pkg.run_installation, version=0, url=file:///Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#run_installation.pkg>",
        "PKLeopardPackage <id=io.continuum.pkg.user_post_install, version=0, url=file:///Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#user_post_install.pkg>",
        "PKLeopardPackage <id=io.continuum.pkg.pathupdate, version=0, url=file:///Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#pathupdate.pkg>"
    )
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP installd[67063]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=110 "An error occurred while extracting files from the package “Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg”." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while extracting files from the package “Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg”., NSURL=file:///Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#prepare_installation.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=io.continuum.pkg.prepare_installation, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe35e82e7d0 {Error Domain=PKXARArchiveErrorDomain Code=101 "archive open failed" UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg, NSFileOwnerAccountID=501, NSFileHFSTypeCode=0, NSFileSystemFileNumber=19481793, NSFileExtensionHidden=false, NSFileSystemNumber=16777220, NSFileSize=809541189, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID=20, NSFileHFSCreatorCode=0, NSFileOwnerAccountName=ME, NSFilePosixPermissions=420, NSFileCreationDate=2023-10-09 18:51:56 +0000, NSFileType=NSFileTypeRegular, NSFileProtectionKey=NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName=staff, NSFileReferenceCount=1, NSFileModificationDate=2023-10-09 18:54:59 +0000, NSLocalizedDescription=archive open failed}}} {
        NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while extracting files from the package \U201cAnaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg\U201d.";
        NSURL = "file:///Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#prepare_installation.pkg";
        NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=PKXARArchiveErrorDomain Code=101 \"archive open failed\" UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg, NSFileOwnerAccountID=501, NSFileHFSTypeCode=0, NSFileSystemFileNumber=19481793, NSFileExtensionHidden=false, NSFileSystemNumber=16777220, NSFileSize=809541189, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID=20, NSFileHFSCreatorCode=0, NSFileOwnerAccountName=ME, NSFilePosixPermissions=420, NSFileCreationDate=2023-10-09 18:51:56 +0000, NSFileType=NSFileTypeRegular, NSFileProtectionKey=NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName=staff, NSFileReferenceCount=1, NSFileModificationDate=2023-10-09 18:54:59 +0000, NSLocalizedDescription=archive open failed}";
        PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "io.continuum.pkg.prepare_installation";
    }
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP installd[67063]: PackageKit: Cleared responsibility for install from 19615.
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP installd[67063]: PackageKit: Cleared permissions on Installer.app
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP installd[67063]: PackageKit: Hosted team responsible for install has been cleared.
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP installd[67063]: PackageKit: Removing client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=19615, uid=501 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer)
2023-10-09 19:55:37+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=110 "An error occurred while extracting files from the package “Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg”." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000099f240 {Error Domain=PKXARArchiveErrorDomain Code=101 "archive open failed" UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg, NSFileOwnerAccountID=501, NSFileHFSTypeCode=0, NSFileSystemFileNumber=19481793, NSFileExtensionHidden=false, NSFileSystemNumber=16777220, NSFileSize=809541189, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID=20, NSFileHFSCreatorCode=0, NSFileOwnerAccountName=ME, NSFilePosixPermissions=420, NSFileCreationDate=2023-10-09 18:51:56 +0000, NSFileType=NSFileTypeRegular, NSFileProtectionKey=NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName=staff, NSFileReferenceCount=1, NSFileModificationDate=2023-10-09 18:54:59 +0000, NSLocalizedDescription=archive open failed}}, NSURL=file:///Users/ME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg#prepare_installation.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=io.continuum.pkg.prepare_installation, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while extracting files from the package “Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg”.}
2023-10-09 19:55:38+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: PackageKit: Bypassing the enforcement checker since the destination is read/write
2023-10-09 19:55:38+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
2023-10-09 19:55:45+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: IFDInstallController 7324A0 state = 8
2023-10-09 19:55:45+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
2023-10-09 19:55:45+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.
2023-10-09 19:55:50+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Package Removal: User opted to remove package.
2023-10-09 19:55:51+01 My-MBP Installer[19615]: Package Removal: Successfully removed package.
```

Any chance someone might have a clue of what could be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Corrupted installer? Redownload and check the hashes https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/reference/hashes/mac-3-gui/

Comment: I will try this!

Comment: Unfortunately, there was no corruption in the installer... Thankfully, the CLI version works, but it would be nice to be able to use the GUI as well.